# update column of table with other column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i hava  table A

```
col1    col2
-------------
1         a
2         hhhh
3         erer
4         sdfsdfds
5          alimd
```

table a has relationshib other tables.

and other table is name  B

```
col1     col2
----------------
1        hhjgjh
2         jkkjerwe
3          jjjjj
```

tables A , B have     milions of records

question  :  i want to  update  col2 of table A with  col2 of table B

the best and  speed  of query  for update

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE A SET A.col2 = B.col2
FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.col1 = B.col1
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/70683/2/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
update tableA
set tableA.col2 = tableB.col2
from tableB
where tableA.col1 = tableB.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will work:

```
update TableA
set col2 = b.col2
from TableA a
inner join TableB b on b.col1 = a.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a SET a.col2 = b.col2 FROM a left join b on a.col1 = b.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update TabA
set col2 = b.col2
from TabB B
where b.col1 = a.col1
```